# How to change X-Axis Interval on Chart.js

Tags: chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I have a line graph on Chart.js and am trying to edit the intervals on the x-axis and the y-axis.

My y-axis intervals are functioning as expected, but my x-axis intervals are not.

I tried the following code

```
let myChart = new Chart(inputChart, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
          labels: [1,2,....,360] // list of values from python script
          data: [360 random numbers here] 
    }
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                id:'main-axis',
                ticks: {
                     stepSize: 40 // this worked as expected
                        }
                   }],
            xAxes: [{
                id: 'main-x-axis',
                ticks: {
                    stepSize: 30 // this did not work as expected
                }
            }]
        }
    }
})
```

With 360 datapoints, I just want to basically see 12 intervals (in increments of 30), but I am seeing 90 intervals in increments of 4 instead. Am I just using the wrong property for stepSize?  If so what is the correct property?

Comment: xAxis values don't get calculated automatically, whatever value we supply in `labels` property in plotted there. Just supply the value you want to see in the xAxis, there is no option for stepSize.

Comment: I tried this, when I supply the 12 labels, I get only 12 datapoints, and lose the other 348 datapoints. Is there not a better way of handling this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It can be done using the `maxTicksLimit` option of xAxes, see this working fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/Lzo5g01n/3/

```
xAxes: [{
    type: 'time',
    ticks: {
        autoSkip: true,
        maxTicksLimit: 20
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 5):

For Chart.js 3.3.2, you can use @Kunal Khivensara's approach with a few changes. You can check the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.3.2/axes/cartesian/linear.html#linear-axis-specific-tick-options). Put `ticks` in `xAxis` in `scales`. Example:

```
...
options: {
    scales: {
        xAxis: {
            ticks: {
                maxTicksLimit: 10
            }
        }
    }
}
...
```